# TensorFlow 2.12 WSL2 Skipping registering GPU devices (Unable to detect cuDNN for some reason)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, wsl-2, cudnn

Found similar issue on TensorFlow Forum [HERE](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tensorflow-on-wsl2-cannot-find-my-gpu-despite-following-the-guide-for-tensorflow2-12/15906) with NO Solution.

I'm running PyTorch 2.0.0 with CUDA 11.8 on the same System (Local Windows 11) with NO Issues, but am facing Issues with TensorFlow 2.12 in WSL2 Ubuntu NOT detecting GPU.

System Details :

- RTX 3060
- Windows 11 Pro with WSL2 (Ubuntu)

Have done the following :

- Installed GPU Drivers from Nvidia's Website [HERE](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx) for the GPU I have
- Followed Step By Step Instruction from TensorFlow Website [HERE](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)
- Referred to [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0S81koZpwPA) YouTube Tutorial

Code I'm trying to run :

```
import tensorflow as tf

print('TensorFlow Version : ',tf.__version__)
print('GPU Name : ',tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

Getting the following error:
[image]

After Everything, the system is unable to get cuDNN for some reason.
(Environment Name is different because I uninstalled WSL and tried everything from scratch again, still got the same issue.)
[image]

How do I resolve this and run TensorFlow 2.12 on GPU ?

Comment: I would like to point out since you included screenshots rather than the text itself, this question is extremely difficult to search for others having this issue.

Answer (score 5):

After tons of trial and error, this works!

- Step 1 : Go to your conda environment
- Step 2 : Run the following command

'''

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

'''

- Step 3 : REBOOT SYSTEM
- Step 4 : Go to your conda environment
- Step 5 : Run the following commands

'''

```
cd $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d

nano env_vars.sh
```

'''

- Step 6 : Delete Everything in there and Paste the following

'''

```
CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)"))

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/:$CUDNN_PATH/lib
```

'''

- Make Sure to Remove any Blank Spaces, so that is looks like this
  [image]
- Step 7 : Save and Exit using : Control+X -> Y -> Enter
- Step 8 : Run the following commands

'''

```
pip install --upgrade pip

pip install tensorflow==2.12.*
```

'''

- Step 9 : REBOOT SYSTEM
- Step 10 : Verify using the following command

'''

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

'''
You should have an Output with the following line

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Finally! Works like a charm. It seems like for some magical reason installation via pip works, while conda doesn't.