# Missing GPU libraries error on tensrflow installation in wsl2

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am encountering this problem  installing tensflow on wsl2 ubuntu. I am using python 3.11 with conda. I have only installed the Game Ready Nvidia Driver on windows.

```bash
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

2024-03-16 10:57:18.247858: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.

2024-03-16 10:57:18.758031: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT

2024-03-16 10:57:19.247708: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:984] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.

2024-03-16 10:57:19.247989: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TensorFlow 2.12 WSL2 Skipping registering GPU devices (Unable to detect cuDNN for some reason)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75937134/tensorflow-2-12-wsl2-skipping-registering-gpu-devices-unable-to-detect-cudnn-fo)